# PRISM/MEF and DEP not working

Tags: reflection, prism, mef, bootstrapper, dep

I'm currently developing an Application with PRISM and MEF. 
This Application will only run on some computers. On some others appears the following message:

> A Problem has has stopped the correct execution of this program. Please close the Application.

(Freely translated from German, excuse me).

I figured out, that this issue is created by the following Code snippet:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
```

or also from

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), Path.GetFileName(fileName));
```

Both solutions to load assembly by assembly don't work. How can I make it DEP-compatible?.

Thanks for your answers :)

// **Edit**: The Reason why I Load assembly by Assembly is, that I wan't to prevent loading assemblies twice to prevent Exceptions while Resolving classes (for example the ServiceLocator from PRISM).

// **Edit 2**: And  I can't add the Application to the DEP exclusion list because not every customer has admin privileges.

Comment: Are you sure this has something to do with DEP? Have you tried to put a try-catch block around these code lines (to check whether and what exception is thrown)?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I figured it now out. It was an combination of PRISM and Microsoft BCL (was requiered for using async in .net Framework 4.0 due to some Libraries). I could not debug anything, because on these clients where no Visual Studio installed.Also it hadn't start anyway.